# selenium Geckodriver webscraping error with firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is a part of my code that webscrapes the odds data from this website "https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2024-01-14&venue=ST&raceno=1". It has been working very well for the past few months, never crashing before.

```
wb = xw.Book("jockeyclub.xlsx")
rc1 = wb.sheets['Race Card 1']

def scrape_odds(url, worksheet):
    # specify the path to the geckodriver executable
    gecko_driver_path = '/Users/nicholaschan/Desktop/hkjcwebscraping/geckodriver'

    # create a new GeckoDriver service instance
    gecko_service = Service(executable_path=gecko_driver_path)

    # create a new Firefox webdriver instance using the GeckoDriver service
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=gecko_service)

    # navigate to the webpage
    driver.get(url)

    # wait for the page to load
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # locate the win and place odds string using its JavaScript variable name
    win_odds_string = driver.execute_script('return winOddsByRace')

    # print the win and place odds
    print(win_odds_string)

    worksheet.range('A26').value = win_odds_string

    # close the webdriver
    driver.quit()


scrape_odds('https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2024-01-14&venue=ST&raceno=1',rc1)
```

However, suddenly, today when I ran it, it was still able to open firefox and follow the link, but then this error message popped up right after.

```
  File "/Users/nicholaschan/Desktop/hkjcwebscraping/scrapodds1.py", line 52, in <module>
    scrape_odds('https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2024-01-14&venue=ST&raceno=1',rc1)
  File "/Users/nicholaschan/Desktop/hkjcwebscraping/scrapodds1.py", line 42, in scrape_odds
    win_odds_string = driver.execute_script('return winOddsByRace')
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 407, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: winOddsByRace is not defined
Stacktrace:
@https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2024-01-14&venue=ST&raceno=1:2:7
@https://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?lang=en&date=2024-01-14&venue=ST&raceno=1:3:8
```

I tried altering the code a bit, fiddling with some bits but every time I ran it, it still crashed. Does anyone know why it has suddenly stopped working after working perfectly fine for a long time?

Comment: I assume content here is loaded dynamically - in that case it's possible that the variable is still not available and you're trying to access it within your code (you can't access something that still doesn't exists). Other possibilities: Maybe there was site update (after few months of working, it's not weird if they updated site). Site might implemented restrictions against scraping?